# Android RuntimeException Failed to resolve attribute at index 24 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext

```
<style name="TextLabel1" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>   
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
**Using this style in Textinputedittext**
```

Its crashing in vivo v3 mobile

Android RuntimeException Failed to resolve attribute at index 24 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:728)
at android.widget.FtPopupToolbar.initItemTextView(FtPopupToolbar.java:425)
at android.widget.FtTextViewPopupToolbar.initToolbar(FtTextViewPopupToolbar.java:113)
at android.widget.FtTextViewPopupToolbar.<init>(FtTextViewPopupToolbar.java:96)
at android.widget.TextView.getEditToolbar(TextView.java:9788)
at android.widget.TextView.moveEditToolbar(TextView.java:9854)
at android.widget.TextView.onPreDraw(TextView.java:4997)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2011)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6006)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:802)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:615)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:585)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:788)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
```

Comment: Post your stacktrace. Where in Java is this thrown?

Comment: I edited my question pls check..

Comment: @karthikudayakumar have you been able to solve it?